# How to edit my method to where it correctly calculates simple interest taking into account the previous year's amount as the new principal?

Tags: c#, principal

Create an internal static void method that receives the original amount of investment principle as a 
named parameter with the default value 1,000.0, the amount of annual interest as a named parameter with the default value of .01 and the number of years duration of the investment as a named parameter with the default value of 5.  The method uses format specifiers to output a simple table showing each year and the value of the investment at the end of each year.  There is no input in this method.  Tip: Look up the currency format specifier.

I am using A = P(1+rt) as the simple interest formula.

```
internal static void Table(double original, double interest, int[] yrs)
    {
        double[] A = new double[6];

        for (int i = 1; i < yrs.Length; i++)
        {
            A[i] = original * (1 + interest * i); //this is the line
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < yrs.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Year " + i + " value: " + A[i].ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't have the signature correct - you're missing the default values for the arguments, and the last argument is specified as an `int[]` instead of an `int`.

Comment: You should make `yrs` an `int` instead of an `int[]`. Then make your loop go from `1` to `yrs` (`for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++)`). Then get rid of the `1 +` in your formula and do `original += original * interestRate * i;` followed by `Console.WriteLine($"Year #{i} value = {original.ToString("C")}");` inside your loop, and get rid of the second loop.

Comment: you have two loops that have the same start and end, why don't you combine them into a single loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the default values for method parameters.
and years should be integer not an integer array.

```
internal static void Table(double original = 1000.0, double interest= 0.01, int years = 5)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++)
    {
        original += original * interest;

        Console.WriteLine($"Year {i} value: {original.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))}");*
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks was going to send it from main. my math is just wrong.